# Which codec and format are Audible downloads?

Tags: audio, sound, audio-processing

Files downloaded with the Audible Download Manager are stored with the .aax file extension, but the information I can find about this format seem to vary.

Regarding [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audible_(service)#Quality#:%7E:text=MPEG-4%20Part%2014), the files are stored in the M4B container (MPEG-4 Part 14), also a quick look into the file header of the .aax files reveals `aax M4B mp42isom`.

Furthermore, regarding [this source](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Audible_Audiobook#Description#:%7E:text=ACELP), the audio is encoded with the ACELP codec.

**If I would decrypt the .aax files DRM with my Audible authentication code without converting the audio, which format and codec would the audio be in?**

(Also I'm not sure if this belongs here or in "Sound Design".)

Comment: Audible books are in m4b format. If you have the authentication code then just use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audible-AAX) (a relatively new version of it) and convert it to m4b format: `ffmpeg -activation_bytes KEY -i book.aax -c copy book.m4b`

Comment: and ACELP isn't really "a" codec, but the math basic for a whole range of codecs; some of them very proprietary, some of them MPEG4 standards, some really obscure, some in wide use...

Comment: @MarcusMüller would you formulate the answer?

Comment: nah, it's not an answer – I don't even know what's inside the encrypted file, I was just raising caution about the cited source.

Comment: I would like to add that I'm not too familiar with codecs, containers and formats and the differences between them. I assumed ACELP is a codec because in the second source it said "they contain data encoded with either the MP3 or ACELP codecs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this post over at the apple stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243670/391392#:%7E:text=aax%20files%20are%20encrypted%20mp4%20/%20m4a%20/%20m4b%20files) says, .aax files from Audible are indeed encrypted m4b files, which means that if I would decode an .aax file without converting it, I would get a .m4b file.

This is possible with the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -activation_bytes XXXXXX -i input.aax -c copy output.m4b
```

The `-c copy` ensures that the data will not be converted.